# Events in hub/factory contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, events, factory

I have written a contract with the hub/factory pattern in which I need to capture the address of the contract that is being created, for this I am using events.

**Contract A**

> Function A1
>
> -- Call to Function B1
>
> --- emit event Contract B

**Contract B**

> Function B1
>
> -- Actions

However, I try making an event with a single contract and it works perfectly, I receive the receipt with the associated events and the resulting elements.

I uploaded to my repository the code I'm using, the contract in question is as follows

https://github.com/DanielZambranoC/Capachain/blob/master/bc/contracts/Capachain.sol

As you can see in line 11 I have changed the content of the event to 'daniel' proving that it was not a problem with the address I was sending, basically I need to return the contract address that was created to the front end to notify the user.

I am using web3js in its version 1.0.0 beta 36 and 55 with my application

In Remix I can see that the log returns the events raised, but I have not managed to capture them from my application.

> Issues on Github
>
> https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2853
> https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6877

---

In the test with only 1 contract you can see that I have the key/value structure of the event, name with their respective values.

In the test with the hub/factory contracts you can see what comes if the events, if I send 2, send me 2 arrays but without content but with raw data, I think that if I sent 100 events, they would sell the 100 array but without information.

**Result with 1 Contract**

```
{
  "transactionHash": "0xdaf5eec6c4b5a767d1d6c4e5ca23b80afcba91b889731358ab0a27c706b981f6",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockHash": "0x1b43bd4ebf57105be29bbbdb80b2b9d12c041fb60b014cdb6d08db46e628353e",
  "blockNumber": 178,
  "from": "0x3377b79a500b6d4a8e2e391b86ebc7f88e99f2c4",
  "to": "0xc3e0cb472f5763a34472afcd546fcce4231a950a",
  "gasUsed": 23031,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 23031,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "status": true,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "v": "0x1c",
  "r": "0xcfe3006057312a461cb0c52c6786eee4f46df6d720da92581e28ec5dab5382f0",
  "s": "0x3d42b3dcc12aa4b902bcdceec6ef1333460ffa8798ef991bcb202a769d173a20",
  "events": {
    "RegistroQueja": {
      "logIndex": 0,
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "transactionHash": "0xdaf5eec6c4b5a767d1d6c4e5ca23b80afcba91b889731358ab0a27c706b981f6",
      "blockHash": "0x1b43bd4ebf57105be29bbbdb80b2b9d12c041fb60b014cdb6d08db46e628353e",
      "blockNumber": 178,
      "address": "0xC3E0CB472f5763A34472AfCd546FCCe4231A950a",
      "type": "mined",
      "id": "log_2191ede5",
      "returnValues": {
        "0": "test",
        "nomre": "test"
      },
      "event": "RegistroQueja",
      "signature": "0x4704303a8919b51a4c52e7794ce51a432970e0b441ef60bf5283fe4520dc5308",
      "raw": {
        "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "topics": [
          "0x4704303a8919b51a4c52e7794ce51a432970e0b441ef60bf5283fe4520dc5308"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result with Hub/Factory Contract**

```
{
  "transactionHash": "0x41bb7b355a3c08d0ae99ae7ccad38c2877688fe97da4d773e70a139c5e246c5a",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockHash": "0xca5049734f587fcd21c80d531433a961365f5778c25a78b861820f9a166ba5c1",
  "blockNumber": 177,
  "from": "0x3377b79a500b6d4a8e2e391b86ebc7f88e99f2c4",
  "to": "0xbf62861d2ab3c1fc05098f71b97886c050fff0b6",
  "gasUsed": 753055,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 753055,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "status": true,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000010000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000400000000000010000000020000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "v": "0x1b",
  "r": "0x5ea7230a484061a85cfea0276597f4cb07be1e866aa7828a6f54ea766c4d8faa",
  "s": "0x2f74d47b31216caf8b3314e34834355f54e61fdb3641662a4e2477a375c18add",
  "events": {
    "0": {
      "logIndex": 0,
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "transactionHash": "0x41bb7b355a3c08d0ae99ae7ccad38c2877688fe97da4d773e70a139c5e246c5a",
      "blockHash": "0xca5049734f587fcd21c80d531433a961365f5778c25a78b861820f9a166ba5c1",
      "blockNumber": 177,
      "address": "0x7bEf0Ce786E1610f9a962C522A5B16b5C8FDbf70",
      "type": "mined",
      "id": "log_4f962706",
      "returnValues": {},
      "signature": null,
      "raw": {
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000664616e69656c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "topics": [
          "0xabf569c29023498f9292dbb4f02d15221cbfeb36d71a45c619158c2f2c8b91f4"
        ]
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "logIndex": 1,
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "transactionHash": "0x41bb7b355a3c08d0ae99ae7ccad38c2877688fe97da4d773e70a139c5e246c5a",
      "blockHash": "0xca5049734f587fcd21c80d531433a961365f5778c25a78b861820f9a166ba5c1",
      "blockNumber": 177,
      "address": "0xbf62861D2aB3C1fc05098f71b97886c050Fff0b6",
      "type": "mined",
      "id": "log_ce96a782",
      "returnValues": {},
      "signature": null,
      "raw": {
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000664616e69656c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "topics": [
          "0x4704303a8919b51a4c52e7794ce51a432970e0b441ef60bf5283fe4520dc5308"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

```
    event RegistroQueja(address contrato);

    function registrarQueja(string memory _descripcion, string memory _nombre, string memory _correo, string memory _fecha) public {
        address contrato = address(new Queja(_descripcion, _nombre, _correo, _fecha));
        contratos.push(contrato);
        emit RegistroQueja(contrato);
```

You can listen the factory's event log.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer... Thats right when using 1 contract pattern, when using factory just getting rawdata in the event log (in post you can see both json returns from each pattern)

I am using this to get the receipt:

```await factory.methods.register registrarQueja(this.state.description,this.state.name,this.state.mail,this.state.date).send({
            from: accounts[0]
        }).on('receipt', function(receipt){
            console.log(receipt);
        })```

Comment: I have posted the same issue in web3 and solidity github https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2853 and https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6877